# Nginx shows no user agent string

Tags: nginx, logging, useragent

I have been dealing with an issue on one of my servers for quite a while now. In short, the server receives massive spikes in load - up to 50 - but the site gets almost no traffic. I know this can be down to poor coding standards, large PHP processes and badly formed MySQL statements however the site runs normally 90% of the time.

I have checked the access logs during the spikes and more often than not its some unknown site crawler thats trying to load a million pages at once and causing issue.

Recently however I have been getting access logs that show something similar to:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2014:08:39:55 -0700] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 20579 "-" "-"
```

where there is no user agent string. Which I wouldn't normally care about apart from this unknown user agent is requesting 100s of pages within a few seconds, which start with HTTP 200s then 499 errors and as the server overloads gets 502 and then 503 errors. So i can't block it in robots.txt or any other blacklisting because i have nothing there to blacklist/disallow.

The stack is a standard ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, MySQL with Varnish caching.

Does anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: Why is the IP address 127.0.0.1? Didn't you set up the real IP module?

Comment: Apologies, bit of a server architecture newby. Have I made a rookie error?

Comment: Just look in  [this page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) as @MichaelHampton suggest. Then maybe you can find the offending IP address.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will take a look. If I had the rep to up vote I would.